# NullPointerException in filter from Ajax Request

Tags: java, ajax, nullpointerexception, servlet-filters

I've recently migrate from Apache to NGINX as web server.
Since that, I get an NPE error with my filters on some AJAX request :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.ulpmm.eev.web.administration.ModifyEleveDossierUtilisateur.VerificationDateEntree(ModifyEleveDossierUtilisateur.java:340)
at org.ulpmm.eev.web.administration.ModifyEleveDossierUtilisateur.modifyUser(ModifyEleveDossierUtilisateur.java:175)
at org.ulpmm.eev.web.administration.ModifyEleveDossierUtilisateur.doProcess(ModifyEleveDossierUtilisateur.java:142)
at org.ulpmm.eev.web.administration.ModifyEleveDossierUtilisateur.doPost(ModifyEleveDossierUtilisateur.java:91)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.ulpmm.eev.utils.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:125)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.ulpmm.eev.filter.RealIPFilter.doFilter(RealIPFilter.java:19)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
```

Here is my RealIPFilter.java :

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (chain != null) {
            if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
                RealIPRequestWrapper rirw = new RealIPRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request);
                chain.doFilter(rirw, response);
            } else {
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        }
    }
```

Line 19 is the one with `chain.doFilter(rirw, response);`

And my SetCharacterEncodingFilter :

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                         FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

        // Conditionally select and set the character encoding to be used
        /*
        if (ignore || (request.getCharacterEncoding() == null)) {
            String encoding = selectEncoding(request);
            if (encoding != null)
                request.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
        }
        */
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        // Pass control on to the next filter
        if (chain != null) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }

    }
```

Line 125 is also the one with `chain.doFilter(request, response)`.

I thought the NPE was on `chain` so I added a test but there is no change.

It seems to occur only with AJAX request. Except for them I don't get the error.

It would be great if anyone have a clue :)

Thank you.

Marc

Comment: try going inside `chain.doFilter(rirw, response);` , and debug

Comment: Your NPE occurs in ConsulteNoteInformation.java:111. What happens there?

Comment: Your stack trace is also showing a class `SetCharacterEncodingFilter` which seems to be yours. A call to the `doFilter` method of this class seems to provoke the NPE (at line 125). Please post that, too. Additionally, it comes back to class `ConsulteNoteInformation`. Here we have a `processRequest` method, which throws the NPE at line 111. How about that code?

Comment: @marthusson : I updated the stack trace with the part I currently test. I checked the line and i found a beautiful error in my production data :(

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose : same explanation, error in my data. I was so obsessed with the filter that I didn't check everything . Thank you for the tip to you and marthusson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As told by @marthusson and @Seelenvirtuose, the NPE is thrown in my data process classes and not in the filters.

The filters are just relays.

By fixing the classes everything is fine.

Thank you :)